# Datastax DSE 5.0.x broken behavior on detecting existing vertex by Text() property value when a search index exists on that field

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

Hi I made this failing Test - I have set the mode to be `Production` and `allow_scans` to `true`. I have also set a materialized index and a search index on property `value`:

```
schema.propertyKey("value").Text().create() 
schema.vertexLabel("Number").properties("value").create()
schema.vertexLabel('Number').index('byValue').materialized().by('value').add()
schema.vertexLabel('Number').index('search').search().by('va‌​lue').asString().add‌​()
```

I am using DSE 5.0.7 with

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.dse</groupId>
   <artifactId>dse-java-driver-graph</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
public class DatastaxTransactionTest {

    private GraphTraversalSource g;

    public GraphTraversalSource getGraph() {
        DseCluster dseCluster = DseCluster.builder()
                .addContactPoint("192.168.1.24")
                .build();

        DseSession dseSession = dseCluster.connect();
        return DseGraph.traversal(dseSession, new GraphOptions().setGraphName("test"));
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        g = getGraph();
        g.V().drop().iterate();
    }

    @After
    public void clean() {
        g.V().drop().iterate();
    }

    @Test
    public void testTransactions() {
        GraphTraversalSource g = getGraph();
        g.V().drop().iterate();
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            boolean exists = g.V().has("Number", "value", "32").count().next().intValue() > 0;
            // this works: boolean exists = g.V().count().next().intValue() > 0; 
            if (!exists) {
                g.addV("Number").property("value","32").next();
                report();
            }
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(1, g.V().count().next().intValue()); //this is 100
        Assert.assertEquals(1, g.V().has("Number", "value", "32").count().next().intValue()); // this is 0!!
    }

    public void report() {
        int vCount = g.V().count().next().intValue();
        int numberCount = g.V().hasLabel("Number").count().next().intValue();
        int number32Count = g.V().has("Number", "value", "32").count().next().intValue();
        System.out.println("added Number (Total Vs: "+vCount+ ", Number Vs: "+numberCount + ", Number 32 Vs: "+number32Count );
    }
}
```

This is trying to insert a Number vertex only if it doesn't exist.. existence over pure count of vertices works fine but doesn't work through indices.. I had huge problems on some of my tests that they were passing only through debugging but not run.. It is as if the indices are not bound to transaction but are eventually updated sometime later.. if that is the case it is a very bad behavior..

Here is the output:

```
added Number (Total Vs: 1, Number Vs: 1, Number 32 Vs: 0
added Number (Total Vs: 2, Number Vs: 2, Number 32 Vs: 0
added Number (Total Vs: 3, Number Vs: 3, Number 32 Vs: 0
added Number (Total Vs: 4, Number Vs: 4, Number 32 Vs: 0
added Number (Total Vs: 5, Number Vs: 5, Number 32 Vs: 0
added Number (Total Vs: 6, Number Vs: 6, Number 32 Vs: 0
[...]
added Number (Total Vs: 97, Number Vs: 97, Number 32 Vs: 0
added Number (Total Vs: 98, Number Vs: 98, Number 32 Vs: 0
added Number (Total Vs: 99, Number Vs: 99, Number 32 Vs: 0
added Number (Total Vs: 100, Number Vs: 100, Number 32 Vs: 0


java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :1
Actual   :100
 <Click to see difference>


    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:645)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:631)
    at com.xxxx.DatastaxTransactionTest.testTransactions(DatastaxTransactionTest.java:53)
[...]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What the data type of the `value` property? If it's `Integer`, could you try to use an Integer value in your queries too?

Comment: it is Text() sure I will try that

Comment: Update 2! having a materialized and search index on ```Int()``` field passes the test. It also works with a ```Text()``` property unless it is **not** in a search index!!  I am using ```schema.vertexLabel('Number').index('search').search().by('value').asString().add()```. The question is why it picks the search index which I have found it is slow at updating itself and not the materialized index which needs to be updated just after the transaction is done.. it is an exact match not regex search..

Comment: Two things to remember:  

 1. Materialised views are updated asynchronously. Search is
    the same.  
 2. When using the fluent API each traversal is a discreet transaction.  
The problem is likely because the index has not finished updating. When using the standard API this is not a problem because the transaction is also queried for matching elements.  
I think you still have a race condition, and if you want to eliminate it you will need to either retry queries with unexpected results or use a secondary index (these are guaranteed to be consistent with the local replica).

Comment: I see! Well I used materialized indices because here (https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/indexOverview.html) it says "Materialized view indexing uses Cassandra materialized views to store data. Materialized views are tables generated from a base table to provide a query based on a different primary key than the base table. This type of index is best used for values of high cardinality or nearly unique values or high selectivity." Why fluent api doesn't search the transaction for matching elements? do you suggest adding another index that is secondary?

Comment: @Bryn btw why it works with just materialized() and when I add search() index it makes the test fail?

Comment: Probably because the search index is being picked and search indices take longer to update.

Comment: MVs are the index type that you would normally want to use. But when using the fluent API you need to be aware that anything outside of a transaction boundary is eventually consistent. If you need to do several operations on new elements you need to make them part of the same traversal and also be aware that it could take time for indices to catch up.

Comment: @Bryn I added a secondary index as well.. it still having the same problem.. I wonder why it picks a search index - it is exact match..

Comment: @Bryn unfortunately fluent api is still very immature.. for example it is very difficult to check if something exists and then add it and keep going on the mutation traversal.. or count a couple things and decide how to continue the traversal.. That's why I was thinking that I might go back to TitanDB/JanusGraph so I can have full control of transactions.. without the need to write really long queries/mutations on the same statement.. this is getting stupid..

Comment: I'm going to check the index selection criteria. I agree it should prefer MVs over Search. I am going to feed your comments back to the team.

Comment: Thanks @Bryn! I will stay tuned!

Comment: @Bryn any update/hotfix to be expected? Thanks!

Comment: @Bryn I tried with `<artifactId>dse-java-driver-graph</artifactId><version>1.2.3</version>` and still see the same issue - is there a Jira ticket for that? Thanks!